# Do supply lines share stored items between settlements?

Tags: fallout-4

I can setup a supply line to share crafting material between settlements. But does this also share any buildings/crafted entities I stored in the settlement?

If not, is there some other way to move them between settlements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, they do not. This is easily tested.

I stored a turret at the Red Racer garage, and couldn't place it in Sanctuary, even after setting up a supply line.

I haven't found any other way to move them.

Comment: Here's to hoping that modding can fix this.