# When storing built items in workshop, what happens to them?

Tags: fallout-4

I wanted to move one of the medium power generators I built to a different location in my settlement. So I thought I could store it in my workshop, run over to the new location and place it from storage.

However selecting "Store in workshop" just removed the item, it doesn't appear in the workshop item list, I didn't get any extra resources (so it wasn't scrapped) and I can't see any section from the workshop menu to access stored items.

Is my power generator just gone now? Or can I access it from somewhere so it can be placed again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do supply lines share stored buildings between settlements?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242808/do-supply-lines-share-stored-buildings-between-settlements)

Comment: @DavidYell that's not even close to being the same question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're stored in the same place you build them from. If you store a generator, there will be a 1 on the generator in the build menu, and when you go to place one, you won't need to pay the resource cost.

Comment: No, when I build I see my resources subtracted even with this number!

Comment: @Vlad I don't know what to tell you. I tested extensively on PC and made a very cursory pass on the XBox, and haven't had a problem. Perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots so I can be sure we are talking about the same things? I hold V, select a bed. At the top right corner I see "Bed (88)" and required resources. (I didn't store 88 beds of course!) When I place it I see that Beds counter is decremented and resources are subtracted (that resource table displays total/required number and I notice that total number changes).

Comment: @Dallium oops, you were right. There is a small number displayed at the *bottom* (just above menu item).

Comment: @Vlad yeah, that's what I mean. That 88 means you have enough resources to make 88 beds.