# Moving furniture from one settlement to another

Tags: fallout-4

I'm trying to move a crafting station and a steamer chest from Sanctuary to the Castle.  I have the two places linked up with a supply line, and the items in the workshop are showing up in both places. However, when I store the crafting station or the steamer chest, they show up in Sanctuary, but NOT in the Castle.

Is there a way to move them, or do I just have to go scrounging for screws so I can make a second crafting station?  I know for the steamer chest, I can just dump its contents into the workshop and access them at the other location. I am currently playing on PC.

Comment: duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242808/108003

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, can't transfer crafted items between locations via the supply line. Only items you can carry in your personal inventory that you have stored in your workshop.

Comment: This answer could use some evidence or citations, but it's not bad. The downvotes are probably because it's a duplicate question.