# Getting items out of Workshop

Tags: fallout-4

I have now made 2 different bases in Fallout 4.

I have the expensive shops in both bases ( the ones that cost 3000 caps )

So yesterday I packed my Sanctuary base up and I went to the Castle.

I was expecting to be able to pull all the packed up items out and use them.

I had 10 turrets, 3 Expensive shops, lot of water purifiers, lot of generators and a whole lot of different stuff.
There seems to be no items that are prebuilt in my inventory or in the Workshop inventory.

When I want to place one of the items in the new base I end up using resources again.

So my question is how do you pull the stored (made) items out of the storage in a different base?

EDIT ( because it was suggested that this is a duplicate )
I am NOT asking about resources. As i know how that works. I am asking about structures here!! I have put many structures in the sanctuary workshop. I cant access those from the Castle. so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Just because I'm not sure it makes sense to link a duplicate question to a duplicate question. Although I agree that the user might not know they need a supply line.

Comment: I have supply lines to all 9 towns i have found so far. They are all linked and i can share the resources from all of my towns.

Comment: @DavidYell again NOT the same thing. I am asking about an item i built in a different settlement.

Comment: You need to read both of the duplicated questions, they cover your question and will solve your issue. The reason you've having lots of duplicate questions is because the site has been flooded with questions about workshop and supply lines since the games release. Everyone claims their question is different, but it really isn't. It's just them explaining their issue how they understand it, but it still comes down to the same game mechanics. Sorry if it seems that way, but if you search `[fallout-4] workshop` you'll see lots of questions.

Comment: Example, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243586/moving-furniture-from-one-settlement-to-another

Comment: If having stuff marked as a duplicate is frustrating, do a quick search beforehand :)

Comment: Whatever rocks your boat. i really dont mind. i got an answer to my question by ESJ. those duplicate answers Arent duplicates of my question as it has to do with different things. I dont live on this site and dont have time to read 5 different questions and answers and then form an opinion based on the 5 different answers. and i did a quick search wich led me to those questions that did not answer my particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored items are marked with a number directly on the icon for the item. If you go back to your original base and try to build one of those shops you will see that there is a number indicating how many you have.

In short pulling the stored items out of storage is no different from building new items. The game will just use the one in storage instead of using resources.

I'm guessing that stored items aren't shared with trade routes. Remeber that when you store an item it doesn't actually appear in the list of items in your workbench. So it probably doesn't count for trade routes.

Comment: Thank you for actually reading my question and providing a valid answer and not throwing duplicate links in my face.