# Fallout 4 settlement storage

Tags: fallout-4

I was wondering if you were able to link your storage between settlements. For example, linking up Sanctuary with The Castle.

Comment: duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242665/108003, related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242808/108003

Comment: You have to establish a trade route, this is done by sending a settler to another settlement. Please note that there are two different "sendings" there is the move and then there is the trading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there are a few things you need to do to make this work however:

1. You need to acquire the 6 Charisma perk, Local Leader (rank 1)
2. You need to attract a settler to one of the settlements you'd like to trade between using the radio beacon in the power -> miscellaneous menu
3. Then, while in building mode, select that new settler with Q (on pc) and assign him to the trade route you want to have

And there you go, any junk you have in your work table will be available in both settlements that are linked by the trade route.

Comment: In my experience, this seems to only affect junk, not items like armor or weapons.

Comment: Woops, yes I believe you are correct. Editing answer