# Do weapons and armor get shared between settlements

Tags: fallout-4

To continue on from [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242808/96299) question, do weapons and armor also get shared between settlements, in their *raw* state? Or are they only usable as scrap when making mods? I have a supply line running between two settlements, but I don't seem to be able to get the weapons or armor between them. Could there be a delay?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is actually transferred what actually happens is the raw materials for crafting can be used even though they are stored at another settlement. Long story short you can't get any of your normal items through the usage of supply lines. The supply lines also allow the the population of settlements with a shortage of water and food to be fed and given water from settlements with a surplus which you will find will come in handy with a particular settlement you will encounter a bit later as it cant produce food of its own.